# Will Queen Release Some Kind of Anthology of Unreleased Material Soon?

Tags: queen, discography

Many fans, including myself, have been waiting for a long time to some kind of Queen Anthology of unreleased material (demos, excerpts, alternate versions), since there is SO MUCH material that they could release, but this release seems that it will not happen while Brian May and Roger Taylor are still alive, even though it sounds cruel, it seems that's the only chance we have, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

There are [a number of Queen compilation albums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_discography#Compilation_albums) already, including Greatest Hits I, II and III, Classic Queen, Queen Rocks, The A–Z of Queen, and Deep Cuts 1, 2, and 3.   Between the Greatest Hits and Deep Cuts collections, there's probably not much of their released material that hasn't been covered.

Comment: I edited my question, because the intention of it was for demos, alternate takes, etc, not actual songs (record songs, b-sides).